# Last 6 Payments

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I need to get the last six payments from a schema that consists of just

Contribution Id 
 DUE Date
 Amount

The payments spread over 7 years and I need to get the most current last six payments only I thought this would do it it as it follows my sql

```
SELECT TOP 6 [ID]
  ,[customerInfo]
  ,[IVACODE]
  ,[Contribution]
  ,[DUE_DATE]
  ,[isActive]
  ,[isDeleted]
FROM [portal].[dbo].[tblPortalContributionSchedule]
where customerInfo='01F6B68B-6FC2-4F9D-B586-6934B8D6C979'
and DUE_DATE <='2016/09/26' 
ORDER BY DUE_DATE DESC
```

Linq Version

```
List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions 
    = portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules
            .Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerId 
                        && a.isDeleted == false 
                        && a.DUE_DATE <=Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/26"))
            .Take(6)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.DUE_DATE)
            .ToList();

foreach (var contribution in _contributions)
{

            AllPayments.Add(new Payments(contribution.ID, Convert.ToDecimal(contribution.Contribution), Convert.ToDateTime(contribution.DUE_DATE), false));

}
```

But its not producing the same results as per below
 [image]

Sorry people i require the answer in linq i need to no is that the correct way of doing it i getting less than exepected

**Edit 1**
This is the query I have so far but I still am not getting the same results as my sql script

```
 List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions = 
portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules.Where(a => a.customerInfo == 
_customerId && a.isDeleted == false && a.DUE_DATE 
<=Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/26")).OrderByDescending(o => 
o.DUE_DATE).Take(6).ToList();
```

**Edit 2**
To show the code that I showed in the video

```
    public List<Payments> getAllPayments(Guid _customerId)

    {
        List<Payments> AllPayments = new List<Payments>();

        List<tblPortalPayment> _payments = portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(a => a.CustomerId == _customerId && a.isDeleted == false).ToList();

        foreach (var payment in _payments)
        {
            AllPayments.Add(new Payments(payment.id, Convert.ToDecimal(payment.paymentDue), Convert.ToDateTime(payment.paymentDate), Convert.ToBoolean(payment.isinArrears)));

        }

  List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions = portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules.Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerId && a.isDeleted == false && a.DUE_DATE<= Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/26")).OrderByDescending(o => o.DUE_DATE).Take(6).ToList();
        foreach (var contribution in _contributions)
        {

            AllPayments.Add(new Payments(contribution.ID, Convert.ToDecimal(contribution.Contribution), Convert.ToDateTime(contribution.DUE_DATE), false));

        }


        var result = AllPayments.OrderByDescending(o => o.paymentDate).ToList(); 

        return AllPayments.OrderByDescending(o => o.paymentDate).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: `Take` should be after `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Are you getting more number of records or the order of records are the problem??

Comment: @IvanStoev can you explain why that is

Comment: Because this is how your SQL TOP query work - first the data is filtered, sorted and then the first sorted 6 records are taken.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OP issue is with LINQ

Comment: @GordonLinoff i did as well as sql as was asking what is the equalivant in linq more than accetable to do that

Comment: @GordonLinoff i removed the sql tag in my last edit

Comment: @IvanStoev please see my last edit the entity version is still not producing the results that the sql server version is ?.

Comment: May be you can highlight what are the differences? I looked at the two pictures in your previous question and frankly I see no difference.

Comment: @IvanStoev the linq one is simply returning blank results no entries even though the dates fall within that date

Comment: which query your image represents ? Linq or TSQL ?

Comment: @Sampath the image represetns the sql query its that result i am trying to reproduce in linq

Comment: OK then can you put the image of Linq ?

Comment: @Sampath I DONT no how to produce the link data for a screen shot ?

Comment: Strange, I cannot even run similar query in LINQ to Entities, because `Convert.ToDateTime` is not supported, so I get a runtime exception. Are you sure you are not catching exceptions and returning empty list? Anyway, try replacing it with `new DateTime(2016, 09, 26)` and see what happens.

Comment: you can get a result on a debug window no ? then you have to video it using `Jing` :D https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html

Comment: @Sampath yes i use jinq already ;-)

Comment: Hi  @marc_s, can you `reopen` this and mark other one as `duplicate` ? here we're going on very good conversation :D

Comment: @Sampath let me no when you finish i wish to removed the video from public viewing

Comment: you didn't do it clearly.on your code you have to put the final value on a variable and put `return` into next line.then you can see the result clearly.we need that result. `var result=your final linq query;` after that `return result;` like that.

Comment: You can change `.ToList()` to `.ToString()` to get the query and run it in MSSQL Studio and compare to desired query

Comment: Thanks a lot @marc_s  :)

Comment: @Sampath you are confusing me

Comment: OK,can you put the same code which you showed us on the video, on your post above under EDIT section ? Then I'll tell you how to do that.

Comment: @Sampath please see edit 2

Comment: this is completely **WASTE** : `return AllPayments.OrderByDescending(o => o.paymentDate).ToList();`.You just need to do like this : `return result;` that is it.

Comment: that is just a side note.but not a solution for your issue.

Comment: @Sampath that is not showing the porblem the result is not gettign any data as i showed in my video

Comment: yes,that thing will `degrade the performance` of you result.not the solution.

Comment: are you referring same db ?

Comment: What is the **type** of the `DUE_DATE`? string??

Comment: @IvanStoev its a date

Comment: Good. Because I noticed you use `Convert.ToDateTime(contribution.DUE_DATE)` which makes no sense if the field is already `DateTime`. Still you shouldn't be able to use `Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/26")` inside LINQ to Entities (EF6.1.3), how is that possible? What EF version are you using?

Comment: can you remove this from the `where` clause and see whether there is any `result or not` ?  remove this `a.DUE_DATE<= Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/26")`

Comment: @Sampath the point is im wanting that as a filter so i am as you see in the result set that is a valid date but yes when you remove the filter the query does return but not the same dates as the sql select statement does

Comment: OK now it is very clear the problem is on your date filter.

Comment: yes but how do we make the query return the same results as the sql already does ?

Comment: please see the answer below and let us know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it as shown below and let us know the result.

```
var dueDateFilter = new DateTime(2016, 09, 26);

List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions = 
    portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules
        .Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerId 
            && a.isDeleted == false 
            && a.DUE_DATE <= dueDateFilter)
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.DUE_DATE)
        .Take(6)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: how would i best paramtise that though if you saw my method was getallpayments i would pass it in via date parameter would this still work ?

Comment: do you mean like this `a.DUE_DATE<= new DateTime(2016, 09, 26)` ? If yes ,then it should work like that too.

Comment: basically i need the date filter to be the most recent date from the first query if that makes since ? it its six months payments of that i am trying to show

Comment: yes,you can do that too.hope that thing is good for another question no ? :D

Comment: no i mean it would be more like this a.due_date = < _payments.paymentDate Last ?? ie it should be the last payment date for that customer should apply the filter if that makes since

Comment: that way it won't work.b'cos `_payments` is a list no.`date` must be a `single` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query

```
SELECT [ID],
 [customerInfo],
 [IVACODE],
 [Contribution],
 [DUE_DATE],
 [isActive],
 [isDeleted]
 FROM [portal].[dbo].[tblPortalContributionSchedule]
 where customerInfo='01F6B68B-6FC2-4F9D-B586-6934B8D6C979'
 and ROWNUM <= 6
 ORDER BY DUE_DATE DESC
```

Comment: jim i shouls have been more clear I wanting to get the more recent no matter what date but also in linq !